# How to get just the URL of an Action in an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the URL of a route using the same syntax as `Html.ActionLink`, but don't know how to do that from my View.

Is there an HtmlHelper extension that works like `ActionLink` but returns only the URL?

For instance, I want to write:

```
<img src="<%= Html.ActionUrl("Image", new { id = 42 }) %>" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out:

```
Url.Action()
```

Aka:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Image", new { id = 42 }) %>" />
```